# IF block is not being tripped even though conditions are being met

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure I am working on that is extremely simple but is giving me some odd issues. Basically if a customer makes a withdrawal on a savings account over 2 times, they got charged a 1.00 service fee per subsequent withdrawal.

The problem is that I seem to be off by one, and it only charges the service fee on the 4th and subsequent transactions.

Here is the stored procedure code:

```
IF @AccountType = 'Savings' AND @Type = 'W'
    BEGIN
        SELECT @WithdrawCount = WithdrawalCount
        FROM Accounts
        WHERE AccountID = @AccountID

        IF @WithdrawCount > 2
        BEGIN
            SET @ServiceCharge = 1.00

            UPDATE Accounts SET Balance = Balance - @Amount - @ServiceCharge
            WHERE Balance > 0 AND AccountID = @AccountID

            UPDATE Accounts SET WithdrawalCount = WithdrawalCount + 1
            WHERE Balance > 0 AND AccountID = @AccountID

            INSERT INTO Transactions( AccountID, EmplNo, Amount, Description, EnteredBy, ServiceCharge, Type )
            VALUES( @AccountID, @EmplNo, @Amount, @Description, @EnteredBy, @ServiceCharge, @Type )

            SET @TransID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
            PRINT @TransID
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @ServiceCharge = 0.00

            UPDATE Accounts SET Balance = Balance - @Amount - @ServiceCharge
            WHERE Balance > 0 AND AccountID = @AccountID

            UPDATE Accounts SET WithdrawalCount = WithdrawalCount + 1
            WHERE Balance > 0 AND AccountID = @AccountID

            INSERT INTO Transactions( AccountID, EmplNo, Amount, Description, EnteredBy, ServiceCharge, Type )
            VALUES( @AccountID, @EmplNo, @Amount, @Description, @EnteredBy, @ServiceCharge, @Type )

            SET @TransID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
            PRINT @TransID
        END

        SELECT @WithdrawCount = WithdrawalCount
        FROM Accounts
        WHERE AccountID = @AccountID
    END
```

I have also done versions where I have an if block for each condition ( >= 3, =3, < 3) with no success as well. Each time I make a different version that should be tripped once the withdraw count reaches 3, it does not. Any advice would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking your withdrawal count before you increment it.  i.e. on the 3rd time the value for withdrawalCount will be 2 not 3 until you update it.  Just check if it's greater than 1 or increment it first